# How to run same class multiple times using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, automation, testng, pom.xml

Is there any way that I can run a class 3 times or more in **Selenium**. So it runs in below order:

- method1
- method2
- method3
- method1
- method2
- method3
- method1
- method2
- method3

```
import com.test
Class A{

@Test(priority =1)
public void method1(){`System.out.print('method1');`}

@Test(priority =2)
public void method2(){`System.out.print('method2');`}

@Test(priority =3)
public void method3(){`System.out.print('method3');`}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no easy way in TestNG to do so. Annotation parameter `invocationCount` only works on method level, not on class, so annotating your class with `@Test(invocationCount = 3)` doesn't work.

As you're mentioning Selenium, my guess is you are trying to automate some repeated actions on a webpage. If so, then I think ideologically your best bet is to extract code from these three methods and just write another test that calls those internals, like this:

```
@Test(priority = 1)
public void method1() {
    stuff1();
}

@Test(priority = 2)
public void method2() {
    stuff2();
}

@Test(priority = 3)
public void method3() {
    stuff3();
}

@Test
public void complexTest() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        stuff1();
        stuff2();
        stuff3();
    }
}
private void stuff1() {
    System.out.print("method1");
}

private void stuff2() {
    System.out.print("method2");
}

private void stuff3() {
    System.out.print("method3");
}
```

It's a good practice to treat each test as atomic test that can either fail or pass, and if you want to test some scenario that does particular set of actions three times, better introduce new test for this and make it clearly and explicitly "tell a story" of test.

Comment: My scenario is like
First: Create
Second: Edit
Third: Approve

This will give me  set of data and in another class i have to use this data to drag and drop and there i need min 2 set of data. And all data have a status approved then only i have to drag. So, for this i have to create 2 set of data by executing same class multiple time. I tried your solution but it not working because after executing first time browser not close and No such element found exception thrown.